# Run code in ViewController from App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my appDelegate.m I'm running this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);
    if([[url host] isEqual: @"success"]){
        RegistrationController *rc = [RegistrationController alloc];
        [rc regSuccess];
    }
    else if([[url host] isEqual: @"fail"]){
        RegistrationController *rc = [RegistrationController alloc];
        [rc regFailed];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

In my registrationcontroller.m I have this

```
-(void)regSuccess{
    NSLog(@"REGSUCCESS!!!:D");
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    WaitController *rc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"waitcontroller"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rc animated:NO];
}
-(void)regFailed{
    NSLog(@"REGFAILED!!!:(");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        _wheel.alpha = 0.0;
}];
}
```

When I connect to my url scheme on my phone, I get redirected to the app, and the console does print out REGSUCCESS!!!:D so I know that the method inside of registrationcontroller.m was called. The problem that I'm having, is that the wait controller is not pushed, or any other manipulation of objects from within the regSuccess method is working. Been searching a fix for this for hours with no luck :(. Please Help.

Notes:
I have already implemented the regSuccess and regFailed methods inside the registrationcontroller.h

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't initializing rc?

Comment: Add some breakpoints in your regSuccess method. When you hit them, confirm that your storyboard pointer is valid, your rc pointer is valid, and finally, make sure that self.navigationController is pointing to an instance of a navigation controller. I don't see where you are instantiating a navigation controller, so that would be my first guess as to what's missing.

Comment: Im not instantiating my navigation controller anywhere... I added one in storyboard, and connected it to my initial view controller. their is no error on any of these lines either. I did initialize rc, but that had no effect on the output. Not sure how to check if self.navigationController is pointing to an instance of navigation controller. If I'm not mistaken, using self.navigationController checks if the view has been pushed onto a navigationController, and if it has, it returns it, which as I'm typing this, I realize that it hasn't been pushed onto a navigation controller (faceslap).

Comment: Just added my navigation controller into the mix, and still get the error. This time I'm sure that the view controller has been pushed onto the navigation controller with the following code

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        RegistrationController *rc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registrationcontroller"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rc animated:YES];

Comment: You def have a valid pointer to self.navigationController when you hit that breakpoint? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Inspecting/Inspecting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009975-CH6-SW1

Comment: If all is well with your navigation controller, then take a look at the new controller's view itself - if you're sure it's being pushed on the stack, check the view's frame and other properties to see if they are what you expect.

Comment: When hovering over self.navigationController, with the breakpoint set after the line of code, nothing appears. Does this mean that their isn't a pointer?

Comment: Another thing worth noting, is that this line of code also does not work from the method.

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        _wheel.alpha = 0.0;
    }];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that `[self.navigationController pushViewController..]` may not be working is that `self.navigationController` may not exist. It's important that a `UINavigationController` have been introduced somewhere along the line, either in a `XIB`, a `Storyboard`, or programatically. It may be worth noting that if the navigation controller is contained by the storyboard you're referencing in your code, this will not work as you'd be trying to push a controller on a navigation controller that is within the controller you haven't pushed yet. The important thing is to verify that if you set a breakpoint in XCode and look at your `regSuccess` method, you should see a valid pointer to `self.navigationController` in the debugger. If you don't have one, you're not going to be able to push anything.

If you've confirmed that the navigation controller exists (and that it's view hierarchy itself has been added to the application's view's hierarchy ), you next need to look at the view itself that you're trying to add. Presumably this would be `rc.view`. What happens if rather than adding to the nav stack, you call:

```
[[self view] addSubview:[rc view]];
```

Additionally, by using either the debugger to examine variables or just logging variables, evaluate the properties of the rc.view. What is it's frame? Where should it be appearing? Is the view not being created properly?

Comment: '[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ _wheel.alpha = 0.0; }];'

Comment: This code ^ doesn't work either when ran from regSuccess. It runs perfectly well from anywhere else in the file. My main concern, is that it seems that since I'm calling this method from the AppDelegate, it doesn't allow me to manipulate the controllers, such as changing the alpha value of objects, or pushing view controllers.

Comment: could you take a look at my code via join.me? That way you get an idea of the whole picture easier?